# Having issues installing fibers

Tags: node.js

Running npm install fibers causes this error. 
Just uninstalled and reinstalled node. nodev5.0.0 npm version 3.3.9 
Tried to remove node_modules and ran npm install again. Was told I needed to upgrade Xcode. I did so and that hasn't helped the issue. Not sure what to do.

```
npm install fibers

> fibers@1.0.7 install /Users/me/project/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o.d.raw { dev: 16777220,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 40855228,
  size: 427,
  blocks: 8,
  atime: Fri Nov 13 2015 20:02:59 GMT-1000 (HST),
  mtime: Fri Nov 13 2015 20:02:59 GMT-1000 (HST),
  ctime: Fri Nov 13 2015 20:02:59 GMT-1000 (HST),
  birthtime: Fri Nov 13 2015 20:02:59 GMT-1000 (HST) }
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/coroutine.o
./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/fibers/src/coroutine.o.d.raw { dev: 16777220,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 40855231,
  size: 433,
  blocks: 8,
  atime: Fri Nov 13 2015 20:03:00 GMT-1000 (HST),
  mtime: Fri Nov 13 2015 20:03:00 GMT-1000 (HST),
  ctime: Fri Nov 13 2015 20:03:00 GMT-1000 (HST),
  birthtime: Fri Nov 13 2015 20:03:00 GMT-1000 (HST) }
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/libcoro/coro.o
./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/fibers/src/libcoro/coro.o.d.raw { dev: 16777220,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 40855236,
  size: 94,
  blocks: 8,
  atime: Fri Nov 13 2015 20:03:01 GMT-1000 (HST),
  mtime: Fri Nov 13 2015 20:03:01 GMT-1000 (HST),
  ctime: Fri Nov 13 2015 20:03:01 GMT-1000 (HST),
  birthtime: Fri Nov 13 2015 20:03:01 GMT-1000 (HST) }
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fibers.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/fibers.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.0.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/project/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
sh: nodejs: command not found
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.0.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "fibers"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.9
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.7 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.7 install script 'node build.js || nodejs build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build.js || nodejs build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/project/npm-debug.log
```